# is there any tool or program to generate database incremental script for oracle db release

Tags: database, release

any tool to generate incremental release script for oracle database.

like Redgate DBComparer for SQLServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366/sql-compare-like-tool-for-oracle).

Other links, tools:

http://www.sqlmanager.net/de/products/oracle/dbcomparer

http://www.sqldelta.com/oraclebeta.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a year late for you but Red Gate now has a schema comparison tool for Oracle!

Try http://www.red-gate.com/products/schema_compare_for_oracle/index.htm